# Is there a word for a question which is meant to sow doubt?

Tags: terminology, questions, figure-of-speech

A rhetorical question is meant to make a statement or point, in the form of a question.  But that is different from a question that is asked with the intent to cause doubt.  For instance, a lot of conspiracy theories are communicated this way, by asking for instance "How can jet fuel melt steel beams?" or "Is the Covid vaccine safe?"  Sometimes these are asked sincerely, sometimes they're asked rhetorically.  But a lot of the time they are asked merely to plant a seed of doubt, and not necessarily to ask or assert anything--the questioner only wants to accomplish a kind of psychological manipulation.  Basically causing the listener to subconsciously think "Well if they're asking the question, it must be because there is cause to have doubt."  There is some kind of pragmatic context that the listener is meant to infer.

The broad phenomenon seems to currently be understood by the popular phrase "just asking questions".  But I'm wondering if there is any more official linguistic name for this kind of expression.

Comment: A very modern and recent term is "[sealioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sealioning)".

Comment: The phrase _just sayin'_, or _just askin'_ (the non-velar nasal at the end is practically required) can have this effect.

Comment: I think you mean "sow".

Comment: Are these not related to the concept of "leading questions"?

Comment: @jogloran I would think a leading question is one such that you are trying to elicit a certain answer.  Not usually seeding doubt.

Comment: this question seems more suitable to the english se than the linguistics one

Comment: @Tristan: I think that question for naming figures of speech are on-topic here.

Comment: @Tristan I don't think the question is specific to English.  I mean, I'm not opposed to the question getting moved if it really isn't appropriate, but this seems like a general linguistic concept.  It doesn't seem extremely different from talking about Gricean maxims.  Of course, particularly asked in the English language, but I would think this same phenomenon can and does exist in every language.  But maybe I'm wrong about that. I am definitely not a linguist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Conversation Analysis I have read of the concept of 'challenges' being used to refer to the case you are describing.

This is a paper that uses the term, maybe it is helpful:
Koshik, Irene. "Wh-questions used as challenges." Discourse Studies 5.1 (2003): 51-77.